# Unable to remove special characters ;:??/?<

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am loading csv file with comma separate value. Buit Tax_Amount column has special characters and it is displacing the values.
How to solve this issue?
I tried below code. But not working.
Tax_Amount Value = SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK'';:??/?<.

```
bad_chars = [";:??/?<."] 
#df['Tax_Amount'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'?', value=r'')
#df['Tax_Amount'] = df['Tax_Amount'].astype(str)
all_columns = list(df) # Creates list of all column headers
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].astype(str)
#df['Tax_Amount'] = translate(None, ''.join(bad_chars)) 
test_string =df['Tax_Amount']
test_string = filter(lambda i: i not in bad_chars, test_string)
```

Comment: Is `??/?` really literal, or perhaps how something in your code represents some unprintable mojibake? Why and how is this junk added in the first place? Is there a way to avoid that somewhere upstream?

Comment: Several of your commented-out attempts look almost correct, but arguably the result of some not so wizardly reading of the docomentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas str allow you to replace unwanted characters. Here is an example of how to solve it with just Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tax_Amount': ['SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK'';:??/?<.']})

pattern = '[:;\?\.<\'/]' # I use \ to ignore characters that are used in regex :)

df['Tax_Amount_Clean'] = df['Tax_Amount'].str.replace(pattern, '').str.strip()

print(df)
```

Results:
[image]

**Explanation**
`pattern = '[:;\?\.<\'/]'` we are telling regex to look at all values that are in `[...]`. But we know that `.?` are reserved characters in regex, so we pass `\.\?' which means treat this as they are and not as reserved key, we ignore also`\’` because we used it as a string. If we used “” then we could just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to delete any character or pattern from string. Here the characters you need to remove is put between the '[]':

```
import re
str1 = "SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK'';:??/?<."
str1 = re.sub('[;:/?<.\'"]', '', str1)
print(str1)
```

output:

```
SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK
```

Comment: This looks like you don't know what `[...]` actually does. The character class matches any single character which is one of the characters enumerated in the class. There is obviously no need to specify any character more than once. This will replace these characters everywhere, not just in this context (which I guess is what the OP wants, out perhaps not what you believe). Also why do you add `"` to the class (twice)?

Comment: @sorry, that " was written twice mistakenly

Comment: You still have `?` three times.

Answer (score 0):

```
bad_chars = [";",  ":", "?", "<" ,".", "'", '/'] 
test_string = list(filter(lambda i: i not in bad_chars, Tax_Amount))
print (''.join(test_string))

SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK
```

(or)

```
Tax_Amount = "SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK'';:??/?<."
bad_chars = [";",  ":", "?", "<" ,".", "'", '/'] 
for k in str(Tax_Amount):
    if k in bad_chars:
        Tax_Amount=Tax_Amount.replace(k,'')

print(Tax_Amount)

SN45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make `bad_chars` a list of separate characters:

```
bad_chars = [';',':','?','/','<','.'] 
test_string = 'N45000000001 40HX750_SEPT17 STOCK'';:??/?<.'
test_string = list(filter(lambda i: i not in bad_chars, test_string))
print(test_string)
```

this way your lambda function will work as you expect it.