# Comma values in a column of CSV - not working code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have CSV file with the below data.

```
**Source data:**

CODE,Name,Value
1,ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ,500
2,GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ,20
```

Expected output:
[image]

But python pandas is not reading the data properly due to comma values in Name column.
I used below link. But not working.
XYZ is truncating in ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ.

```
pattern = '[:;\?\.<\'/]' # I use \ to ignore characters that are used in regex :)
df['Name_Clean'] = df['Name'].str.replace(pattern, '').str.strip()
```

[Unable to remove special characters ;:??/?<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032987/unable-to-remove-special-characters)

Comment: The data you have shown Is `Source data` is a column? ow what your desired output would be, can you show that?

Comment: Source data is file name. Name is the column name. Source value =ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ & Target value=ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ. But XYZ is missing from Name

Comment: what is expected output you see ?

Comment: Hi @KarnKumar, updated the post. Please check. Thank you

Comment: Okay, so what if you do `df =  pd.read_csv('source_data.csv')` because its comma delimited file so it should work.

Comment: ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ  this Name value spliting... because of comma inside it.

Comment: see the solution if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried below which is one doable solution using `Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame` with `pandas.read_fwf()` method and assign a temporary column name `col1`.

### You Raw Data:

```
$ cat source_data.csv
CODE,Name,Value
1,ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ,500
2,GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ,20
```

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df =  pd.read_fwf('source_data.csv', names=['col1'])
>>> df
                        col1
0            CODE,Name,Value
1    1,ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ,500
2  2,GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ,20
```

### Solution:

So, when you will use `str.extract`, you will see `NaN` values which you can drop with `dropna()` and then use `rename` to assign the desired column Names as extracted names are Just integers ..

```
   >>> df.col1.str.extract('(\d+)\,(\D+)\,(\d+)')
     0                     1    2
0  NaN                   NaN  NaN
1    1     ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ  500
2    2  GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ   20
```

Desired:

```
>>> df.col1.str.extract('(\d+)\,(\D+)\,(\d+)').dropna().rename(columns={0:'CODE', 1:'Name', 2:'Value'}).dropna()
  CODE                  Name Value
1    1     ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ   500
2    2  GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ    20
```

OR

In case you want to rename the columns names creating a dict then try..

```
>>> cols={0:'CODE', 1:'Name', 2:'Value'}
>>> df.col1.str.extract('(\d+)\,(\D+)\,(\d+)').dropna().rename(columns=cols).dropna()
  CODE                  Name Value
1    1     ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ   500
2    2  GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ    20
```

### Regex Explanation:

```
'(\d+)\,(\D+)\,(\d+)'


1st Capturing Group (\d+)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

\, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

2nd Capturing Group (\D+)
\D+ matches any character that\'s not a digit (equal to [^0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

\, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)

3rd Capturing Group (\d+)
\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Karn Kumar, I have 25 columns with dates, text,numbers,alpha numerics. I confused with d,Ds. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best solution is to correct your CSV. Starting from

```
CODE,Name,Value
1,ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ,500
2,GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ,20
```

and applying

```
<./input.csv sed -r 's/([0-9]+),(.+),([0-9]+)/\1,"\2",\3/g' >./output.csv
```

you will have a properly formatted CSV

```
CODE,Name,Value
1,"ABC (CEF) CO.,XYZ",500
2,"GOOD VALUE  CO., XYZ",20
```

Some notes about the command:

- `sed` is a command line utility that parses and transforms text (you can use it in every operating system);
- `<./input.csv sed` to send the content of your input file to `sed`;
- `s/([0-9]+),(.+),([0-9]+)/\1,"\2",\3/g` is the search and replace via regex https://regex101.com/r/WRzcEW/1 (in the upper right part you find the explanation);
- `>./output.csv` to save the output

Comment: Hi All, I did not understand the code...<input.csv sed -r 's/([0-9]+),(.+),([0-9]+)/\1,"\2",\3/g'   Please help me

Comment: Hi @PythonWizard I have added some final notes for you in my reply